# Move tags field to top when creating/editing a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, design

Since we have a common problem with people putting tags in the title wouldn't it make sense to have the editor hint that isn't appropriate by the flow? I think we could move the tags at the top to allow a natural flow and maybe people will recognize that they don't need to put any tags in the title.

Comment: Related: [Could the “Tags” textbox be above the “Body” text area?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79208/could-the-tags-textbox-be-above-the-body-text-area)

Comment: Also Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214556/revisit-putting-tags-box-under-title-box-on-asking-question-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should tags be relocated to the top of question pages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338198/should-tags-be-relocated-to-the-top-of-question-pages) [ Cleaning up by connecting duplicate requests over the years together ]

Comment: @OlegValter nope

Comment: @OlegValter, I think you have the duping backwards...

Comment: @StephenRauch - I do not think I do :) There is no requirement we close against the oldest one reported (especially when neither have any official response) - and the newer one has more details too. Either way is fine by me, of course, but *just* closing against the oldest reported question is not going to help anyone, just saying.