# Should "tags" be filled before "title"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

When I approach asking a question I think about the tags first.  In fact, I often end up filling in the tags first, then jumping back up to fill in the title and question body--and then my tags are ignored in the "Questions that may..." suggestions (["Similar Questions" search should take the tags into account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269706/85269)).

I imagine that meta-aware SO "power-users" think about questions the same way: break it down by category (especially obvious things like language, SDK and API) then craft a narrative question (which may or may not contain the tags, by the way, depending on the flow of the question sentence--not entering that fray here).  It would be great if the UX of the page matched the way we think about our questions: **put "Tags" at the top of the page, not the bottom.**

Further, this would seem to *encourage* better question asking, in that makes the asker start to break down the question in a way that suits the purposes of SO, and could even be a point where tag descriptions could keep them on-topic for the site (e.g., for "excel" it could specify that power-user Excel questions belong on SuperUser, etc.).  And of course, they could narrow to some extent the suggested-question search.

Comment: +1 I like this idea. Although I do wonder if for some people, adding tags before they flesh out the question would cause them to add broader tags. I often figure out what I'm actually asking while I'm in the process of writing the "narrative."

Comment: There's a problem with this approach, normally users rely in suggested tags ([the exacts numbers are not known to anyone actually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231947/213575) but more often than not, that's the impression they give) which in turn relies on [the content of the question itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907/213575) so inverting the order may be akin to putting the cart before the donkey

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me, but it has been suggested a couple of times before: [Move tags field to top when creating/editing a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269316/move-tags-field-to-top-when-creating-editing-a-question)