# Feature Request: move tags to top while reviewing posts

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

While browsing questions I will often be filtering by tags, so I have some context and expectation for questions I open.  When I go to the review queues, however, frequently the questions are long enough that I cannot see the tags, so I either have to read the question without knowing what topics the author thought might be relevant or scroll down to see, then back up to start reading.

If the tags were available at the top in addition to the bottom I could get the context first then I feel do a better job reading the question.

I know many questions can be evaluated absent knowing whether it's a Java question or a bash question or a sqlserver question, but I find I waste a lot of mental energy just trying to figure out what the post is about before I can get into evaluating it.

I think this similar in spirit to [Move tags field to top when creating/editing a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269316/move-tags-field-to-top-when-creating-editing-a-question), but I actually am fine with where the tags are for editing questions.  This is just for a viewing the tags more quickly when in the review queues (e.g., Triage), without wanting to edit the question at all.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214556/revisit-putting-tags-box-under-title-box-on-asking-question-form