# In Triage, move Tags above the question

Tags: feature-request

While doing Triage, I frequently find myself having to read a fair bit of user text before I realize that the question covers a language or technology where I'm not really competent to judge the question. Having made that determination, I press the Skip button.

My observation is that this process could be made considerably quicker if I could see the Tags attached to the question without having to scroll down. (Presumably making the Triage process quicker and simpler would encourage more people to take part, hopefully improving user feedback and question quality.)

My suggestion, then, is that, in Triage mode at least, the Tags be displayed at or near the top of the window.

I'm aware that there's another discussion about [moving Tags up in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294270/feature-request-move-tags-to-top-while-reviewing-posts). I think that this merits a separate discussion (assuming the other isn't adopted).

Comment: Related (not duplicate): a request to implement [tag filters in triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297317/why-is-there-no-filter-in-triage-review)

Comment: And the first answer there is quite relevant to this question. Thanks @ryanyuyu