# Search in Ask Question should filter or prioritize by tags

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I just noticed a duplicate question in the Go language tag that has been repeating in various forms pretty much since forever.

I thought, "Why don't people find the duplicate question when asking? Why doesn't the search help them?"

I discovered that the search does not filter by tags apparently. Generic words like "interface" and "nil" appear in almost every programming language, so the search results are not exactly useful.

I propose asking for the tags FIRST, then the question title search can be filtered and/or prioritized by the tags.

Comment: Searching for "[go] nil interface" turns up perfect matches for the go language.

Comment: If you use the go tag yeah. So why does the Ask Question search as you type your question title not use tags?

Comment: So both of you now go back and read my proposal...

Comment: You want them to search *while* they type a question instead of *before* they decide to ask?   Novel.

Comment: @HansPassant Have you asked one lately? That is what it already does but it needs tags.

Comment: There are a few questions about this topic showing up in the Related section to the right... Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269316/ and on the OverMeta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79208