# Stop asking me to check existing questions if there are no relevant matches

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, ask-question-form

Every time I ask a question, I have to click submit twice. First because I want to ask a question and then a second time because SO is spamming me with possible duplicate questions.

I never check for duplicate questions before I ask because because SO will check for me.

And then I never review the SO recommended possible duplicate questions because every time I look they are very obviously unrelated.

*For context, the top duplicate suggestion while I am typing now is "Why not solve the thanks a lot problem by prompting the user to upvote the question?" which is not clearly not related to duplicate questions.*

---

This situation could be much remedied if SO would only show recommended duplicate questions when some confidence threshold is met. In my experience this threshold should be at least "top 10% confidence", but depending on how original your questions are YMMV.

Comment: Given the fact that 90% of all questions have absolutely awful titles no existing check will ever have any reasonable confidence level that the recommendation tool will be able to use.

Comment: It's still so bizarre to me that SE has yet to update that search to [take tags into account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312141). That dialogue [doesn't even _show_ tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJPZn.png) on the suggested duplicate questions... Not that showing tags would make it search better, but still, it'd be nice to be able to quickly scan past the Java post [that gets suggested for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar0Q0.png) a C# question, and similar.

Comment: “I never check for duplicate questions before I ask because because SO will check for me.” - You should. The matching algorithm sucks. I have personally flagged hundreds of questions as a duplicate to questions not even listed as being relevant questions.

Comment: Can you please clarify why suggested feature is beneficial for the site? (I don't think speeding up question submission can provide any benefits)

Comment: @zcoop98 android java too, to really put the cherry on top. Terrible.

Comment: If search SO was useful (with a short query) then the recommended duplicates (which is a HUGE QUERY) should be MORE USEFUL. qed. If this is not true then this is a valid issue, vote it up.

Answer (score 13):

> I never check for duplicate questions before I ask because because SO will check for me.

Unfortunately you should be doing exactly this. SO's system just checks for similar words in the title, which is why it seems unrelated. But please ensure you search before posting. It doesn't take long, but **make sure** to use keywords to narrow your search of what you *really* want.

I usually do this and ignore SO's suggestions (at least until SO improves its search algorithm).

Comment: It sounds like you agree with me--that SO recommended duplicate search box is broken and it is hurting usability. But for some reason people are voting up your answer (recommending that visitors change their behavior) and not my question (recommending a better product).

Comment: Yup I do agree with you on that part, but I dont agree with you on how you don't check for duplicates before posting and relying on an unreliable engine search that SO provides for us users to use for finding duplicates. People are probably downvoting because the main part of your question isnt about a better search engine of SO (and because this has been asked before too)