# Move a question’s tags to directly under the title

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

Logically, the tags on a question are **part of the title**.
(And indeed, posters are discouraged from putting tag words in the title because "that is what tags are for".)

While reading a title, one should see the tags right there, below the title. This would a) make it easier to realize whether a question is relevant to the technology you are searching for, b) make it harder for answerers to overlook the tags, and provide an answer for a different technology or language.

Currently, one must look TWO places to gather the relevant info: the top of the post and the bottom of the post. This is inefficient. (And for those of you for whom this is a non-issue, realize that different people's minds work differently; there is an abundance of research that most people, when reading anything, do not do a complete parse of available info; there is a tendency to stop as soon as one has "gathered enough info".)

An alternative solution would be to put the tags TWO places - where they are now (at end of post), and immediately below the title.

Comment: ...but *why* should I see the tags if the title and body of the question provide all of the context I need?

Comment: @Makoto - One could just as well ask "why have a title at all, if the body of the question provides...". Or ask "why bother having tags"?  The point, of both the title and the tags, is to provide an **at-a-glance summary** of the topic.  To me, the current situation is like starting a document with an "Executive Summary" paragraph .. which stops half-way through, and says "see continuation of summary at end of the article."

Comment: Off-topic, but RPG.SE enforces "no tags in titles" pretty strongly and has problems with answers from the wrong edition of a game, and the rules-as-written tag carries it's own special rules, so there's at least one site that would benefit from this.

Comment: *easier to realize whether a question is relevant to the technology you are searching for* If you're searching for a specific technology, aren't you using the tag(s) for it anyway?

Comment: Similar request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269316/2675154

Comment: @Makoto Considering [tags shouldn't be in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), it's not always the case that the title & body contain all the context needed. "How do I serialize an object to JSON? Here's what I've tried..." would have completely different answers depending on the tag.

Comment: @Rob yes, except that such a question should contain the author's code, which should make it clear which language is being used. (Still, tagging such a question with its language is mandatory IMHO.)

Comment: @Rob:  Recent editing wisdom states that having blatant tags is discouraged, but quantifying the topic space is acceptable (e.g. the difference between having your title have the tag "spring" and asking, "How do I mock a Spring bean?").  I would expect your example title to include the context of the language as well, such as, "How do I serialize an object to JSON in Python?" (It'd be fairly broad unless there was sonething redeeming in the body since serialization is a broad topic and there are many ways to tackle it.)

Comment: I assume OP refers only to the browser version. On Android app the tags are already found immediately below the title

Comment: So this would make it useful only for when you come from external sites right? Anywhere from SO, you'd first have the tags displayed at most 3 lines below the title, with just a small excerpt of the body in between. So I could think of a better FR asking to include tags (at least the 2 main ones) in the heading that got parsed by search-engines crawlers, so we don't even have to visit irrelevant pages. (not sure how feasible it is, I s**k at SEO...)

Comment: Interestingly, this is how the mobile theme works: the tags are displayed below the title, above the question body. I know this because I recently visited a new Stack Exchange site via HNQ on my phone, and it hadn't stored my preference of using the desktop site, so it took me a good deal of time to find the tags.

Comment: I disagree. Currently it have a good place. The bottom contains tags, action links and spaces for close, lock reasons, etc.

Comment: @Rob If the question doesn't explicitly clarify relevant technology questions, it's a bad question, period, whether or not the title or tags clarify it. That said, "tags shouldn't be in titles" is not some kind of blanket ban on all occurrences of the word "python." That would counterproductive and pedantic

Comment: @Moritz - I'm not talking about the question list; I rarely get to a question via that list. Go to some question. (using desktop browser, not mobile) If it is a fairly lengthy question, then the tags are way down at the bottom of the question. Now imagine that you got here from somewhere else, *not from that list of questions*.

Comment: I don't really see a benefit for this.  The only thing that adding the tag to under the title does for me is move the text body down.  This is not a good thing.

Comment: This would be extremely useful when reviewing questions. Instead of scrolling down two pages of text to see if you have competence/interest to go question trough in details you could see that instantly under the title.

Comment: @SagarV For UI component the type or the functionality it provides is not IMHO a primary basis where to put component. It is only good for archiving things. We should keep usability as our main focus.

Comment: As King of the Internet, I order you to do this.

Answer (score 8):

I'm kind of on the fence with this, as I can see *some* benefits for this, but I'm not sure there are enough use cases to warrant a change. This answer is simply to highlight my navigation experience to see if others agree.

**My Question Navigation Experience**

My question navigation experience generally boils down to me navigating to one of my favourite tags, so straight away I know a specific tag is involved. Secondly, I would scan down the question list, assessing the titles and any additional tags that are displayed before viewing posts, which kind of covers your point of seeing the title and tags together.

[image]

**Navigating via Search Engine**

I guess there are cases where navigating to a question directly doesn't give you the above experience, for example coming straight from a search engine. In these cases, again in my experience, I would generally start my search with a tag name effectively, for example I may search:

> SQL Server Select * from table

Or:

> C# linq orderby

Which would again give me a direct indication of the tags that are likely to be involved.

**Size of Post on Desktop**

The next thing to consider I'd say is the size of the question. If a question isn't too long, then the title and tags would all be visible without a requirement to scroll, and I'd *hazard to guess* that more posts would be of the size that doesn't require a scroll to see the tags than not,  but I have no stats back this up. Granted, the title and tags aren't together but they are still visible.

Would it be odd seeing tags above and below the question in these scenario?

[image]

**Mobile View:**

I've noticed also, as Cody Gray states in comments on the OP, that the mobile view does have the tags above the post. I guess from a UX perspective, having  less screen to show the tags is the reason behind this decision:

[image]

Comment: I think the reason the mobile view shoves the tags up there is because it already put the voting/favorite buttons beside the title. So a lot of vertical space would've been wasted if they hadn't found something to put there.

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess so, would be nice if we could have some official comment about the decision behind it.

Comment: I totally agree with all the answer. You can see tags BEFORE clicking on the question. So you already know what you are searching for. To me, the list of tags at the bottom of the question is just a reminder of which technologies has been used, IN CASE there are a lots

Comment: @AntoinePelletier as said earlier here, you don't necessarily arrive on the question from the questions list, you can also arrive on it from a web search or a link from elsewhere, where tags aren't displayed.

Comment: @Veve yes, in the case you have reached a question and you don't even know how or why, or what you where searching for ? But you ended here. In that case i would just say... start using the site like it's meant to be used ? Still... i kind of get your point. Personally i like where tags are placed, just my opinion :)

Answer (score -1):

No.

There are many pages with list of questions. In all of them things are pretty clear, because title and tags are very close (see @ChristianGollhardt answer). Problem is rather different: many users are still putting tags into the title. So you see [it rather twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK683.png).

The inner links (duplicate posts links, in comments, in questions/answer) and outer links (from google) in any case **require investigation**. So you have to scroll down to read comments, to read answers, to read comments to answers, etc. Including tags.

There is no need to improve anything, as scrolling down to tags brings you close to comments, which **you want to read** anyway.

Answer (score -13):

I disagree.

In the question view we already have the tags next to the title:

[image: Tags]

That is the time, where I decide:

- Do I have the knowledge to answer it?
- Do I have enough knowledge to moderate it?

At this time, I already know the topic, and technology (tags) used.

If I click on it, I just want to know the context. I am not anymore interessted in tags.

After reading all the context, it would be more plausible, that a reminder is needed, which exactly technology this was about.

As a researcher of course we don't use the question page. But I also never had the case where I searched for something and got a result that was irrelevant to the technology I have searched for. Googles PageRank<sup>tm</sup> is doing a good job.

I just noticed, why above paragraph is at least for me true: We already have the top tag in the title element of every page:

[image: Tag in title]

[image: Tag not in title]

So, please **don't** change.

Comment: You don't necessarily find all questions from the home page. I find a lot of questions from Google, and Google doesn't show the tags.

Comment: @DonaldDuck most of the time if you use google to find a question you're looking for an answer not answer it

Answer (score -18):

Tags are virtually never necessary for a reader to discern the meaning of a question. (Only a rather badly written question could require it.) Additionally, Google is *quite* good at steering you toward questions for your desired language. The bottom line is that most readers don't care about tags once they've reached the question.

The primary purpose for tags is filtering for people looking to *answer* questions in their field of expertise. However, all this filtering is done *before* the answerer reaches the question. They already have the site filtered to their interesting tags or searched specifically for that tag. The bottom line is that most answerers don't care about tags once they've found a question.

In short, tags are essentially noise for everyone who arrives at the question. That's why they're out of the way at the bottom. Please keep them there. Once I'm done reading the title, I want to read the question, not scroll down more to get at the meat.

Comment: *The bottom line is that most readers don't care about tags.* do you have anything to back that rather bold statement?

Comment: @TimCastelijns The fact that no one has complained about this for the past 10 years. Do you have any evidence for the bold statement that the current position causes problems? The original post sure doesn't provide any. What evidence do you have that readers are confused about what broad technologies and topics a question addresses before they arrive at it?

Comment: I do not, but I didn't post here to defend the feature-request, I posted here to ask you where you pulled that information from

Comment: @TimCastelijns Where's your comment asking for evidence from the OP, then?

Comment: We are discussing *your* statement, not his

Comment: @TimCastelijns No, we're discussing the question of where tags should be placed. Saying that tags are unimportant to readers is not more drastic than saying they're important to readers. So why are you only demanding evidence from one side? Either we both need it or neither of us do. So which is it? I have the benefit of almost a decade of a successful layout where tags are de-emphasized, and the OP is suggesting a course of action that incurs costs. Isn't it even *more* important for the OP to provide evidence that a problem even exists, if you're going to ask for evidence?

Comment: *we're discussing the question of where tags should be placed* no we are not. I asked you a question about a statement you made, not about the placement of tags or what that would incur. But you are trying really hard to avoid having to discuss it, so I'll take the hint and move on

Comment: @TimCastelijns I pulled it from thinking about it. Tags provide very little information. They assign broad categories to a question for classifying and filtering purposes. It's just not their purpose to be anything that a reader *needs* to look at to figure out what the question is asking. Questions are supposed to be clear; if it's impossible to understand the question without the tags, the question needs editing badly. This isn't something I think needs to be proven with statistical analysis. I've clarified a little in the answer, as it occurred to me there may be some confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I agree for the most part