# Consider moving tags into question header to discourage tags in titles

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, user-interface

Preventing tags in titles seems to be an uphill battle. What about this simple layout change, which *may* positively impact UX and cause fewer tags in titles: **move the tags just below the question title for both new questions and question view?**

I think this is worth an experiment.

Suggested question layout:

[image: Question title with tags below it]

Suggested new question layout:

[image: New question title with tags below]

Comment: But for people on small screens this will move the actual question even further down the page than it already is

Comment: @JeanneDark it doesn't as it has no answers at all. Five years later and the problem is still here.

Comment: @Nick Good point, small screen UI might be different in terms of layout and/or behavior.

Comment: [Is a question a duplicate if the duplicate has no answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277950/11682469)

Comment: @JeanneDark I didn't say it was not a duplicate. What I say is that the other question provides no answers to the suggestion and that after five years dividing that and my questions, the problem is still here and I believe it is worth reconsidering past decisions, if any were made.

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356614/move-a-question-s-tags-to-directly-under-the-title?noredirect=1&lq=1) is strongly related, but it's not about _editing/creating_ a question, as far as I can see.

Comment: [How to renew an old feature request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364131/11682469)

Comment: from my interactions with at least a couple of "title-taggers", they really believe they are helping "searchability" of questions (and are ready to go to war with any editor that tries to fix their precious posts), so I am not sure this will help... It might make the ridiculousness of adding tags to titles more apparent, though, so the idea is not without merit. As for the UI on small screens, it is a non-issue because right now SE wastes a lot of screen space that can be repurposed for something actually useful.

Comment: @OlegValter This is the kind of answer I would be looking for. Thanks.